# driver not getting recognized by other scenario in karate-ui

Tags: ui-automation, karate

When we do ui automation we have to break it in different scenario so definitely i will need login only once
now i made a feature login.feature where i write below lines

```
Given driver 'example.com'
```

This i will call in my feature file as below

```
Feature: Test all scenarios
BackGround: login once
  * callonce read('login.feature')
Scenario : test drop down
  * driver.click('#someId')
Scenario: check the table aftr drop down clicked
  * driver.highlight('#someId')                     # here driver is not recognized
```

Now at this second scenario neither the highlight alone not driver.highlight is working.
I know i will be suggested something like scenario should be independent but obviosuly i wont be logging and closing browser again and again right ?
Please suggest me what can i do to achieve this

Note :  i am using 0.9.6.RC4 karate version which is latest

Comment: also `callonce` is NOT supported for `driver` I will add this to the documentation. if you find this troublesome, please contribute code. or feel free to switch to some better framework

Comment: Hey thnaks for quick reply just wanted to say i tried as below 

karate.configure('ssl', true);
    karate.configure('driver', {
        type: 'chrome',
        start: false,
        webDriverUrl: config.endPoint,
        ssl: true,
        addOptions: ['--ignore-certificate-errors']
    });
    return config;

And now getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
Help plz

Comment: lol nope. please search stack overflow for that error.